# Rally Velocity Chart Story Point Carry-over

Tags: rally, agile, scrum

I am trying to figure out how to find/create a velocity cart in Rally that will also measure/show the story points that are carried over/moved to the next sprint. The velocity chart Rally offers only measures "Accepted during Iteration", "Accepted after Iteration", and "Not Accepted". Is there a custom Rally app for this or some other solution?